# codeigniter sum query for single column

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

Have a query that I'm trying to return the sum result of the columns where the value is over 10,000. I've tried adding sum(value) as total to the query but it's not working.

My code is:

```
    $this->db->select('sum(value) as total, date, member_id');
    $this->db->where('member_id', $_SESSION['sess_user_id']);
    $this->db->where('cost.value >', '9999');
    $this->db->where('cost.date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)');

    $query = $this->db->get('orders');

    return $query->num_rows();
```

here's the raw SQL output:

SELECT sum(value) as total, `date`, `member_id` FROM (`steps`) WHERE `member_id` = '1' AND `cost`.`value` > '9999' AND `cost`.`date` = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)

Comment: you need to add group by date, member_id

Comment: group by date, member_id?

Comment: Tried - and it's still not working.

Comment: i am not familiar with coedigniter, can you post regular SQL

Comment: Not working is vague, what do you expect and what do you get? Also you're talking about sum but you return the number of rows

Comment: Just check SELECT * FROM (steps) WHERE member_id = '1' AND cost.value > '9999' AND cost.date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) and see what results come first. May be you miss something in where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not clear what do you want, but:

If you need the sum of the values for a specific user where the date is 5 days ago, your query should work, but there are 2 problematic things:

1. This is probably a typo, but in your code, you get the data from "orders" and in your raw query, the data is got from "steps". If it is not a typo, you are looking in the wrong place.
2. In your "where", you are asking for rows where "date" is equal (=) to 5 days ago, but using "now()" you are asking for rows with date **exactly** 5 days ago, this is, including hour, minute and second.

If you need the number of rows where the value is 10000 or more of a specific user, you must not use "SUM" or you always gonna get 1 as result (or null). Besides that, again, the date is exactly 5 days ago, including hours, minutes and seconds.

On the other hand, you say you want the number of columns, i think you need the number of rows, but if you really need the number of columns, you need to change

```
SELECT sum(value) as total, date, member_id
```

to

```
SELECT *
```

and

```
return $query->num_rows();
```

to

```
return $query->num_fields();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
function cart_product_join()
    {
        $this->db->select('products.product_id,cart.product_id,SUM(products.special_price*cart.product_qty)');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->join('cart', 'cart.product_id = products.product_id', 'right');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $result;
        //$result=$this->db->last_query();
        //echo $result;
    }
```